# In MSBuild, can you turn off the unresolved reference check?

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops, msbuild, azure-pipelines

I'm testing MSBuild in DevOps for building SQL Server database objects - stored procedures, functions, views, tables, etc.  We're wanting to create the database project files once and not have to touch them again when we add new items, like a new table, stored procedure, etc.  I modified the .sqlproj file so the Build Include has *.sql instead of listing everything, like Build Include=Stored Procedures\*.sql instead of Build Include=Stored Procedures\sproc1.sql.  I tested this with a small database with just a few objects and it works great.

Now I'm trying this with a database with a large number of objects.  I created a database project, did a schema compare with an existing database to get all of the objects into the project, then committed everything back to DevOps and ran my build.

I'm getting error:

> SQL71561 View has an unresolved reference to object xxx.

Any idea's how to get rid of this?  It would really be nice if I could just tell MSBuild to ignore this error, but I'm not finding anything saying that can be done.  I figured out how to ignore warnings, but not errors.  I saw things saying to add a database reference to master.  That didn't work.  I also saw things saying to add a reference to a .dacpac.  If I do this, what happens when we add a new table?  Do we have to keep updating the .dacpac we are referencing?    Right now, the database that has the objects being  referenced isn't in my DevOps testing environment.  If I put them in DevOps, how do I tell MSBuild where to look for the objects referenced?  Or will it just automatically find them?

In case it matters, I'm using Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Your project won't build if you don't take care of those errors. Is that a problem for you?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out, how to fix these errors.  The code works fine, it's just the build says it can't find the referenced object so it's throwing an error.  I'm trying to figure out how to make MSBuild find the referenced object.

Comment: You have to add a reference to the .dacpac as you said. That dacpac doesn't _have_ to be the most up to date copy of it, but it _does_ have to contain any objects your project actually references. On my projects where I have .dacpac references, the only time I update them is typically when an object has been added to the referenced project that I need. Otherwise, I tend not to care if the dacpac I am referencing is maintained 100% up to date

Comment: FWIW, the addition of a reference to `master` is if you are calling things like system views (e.g. `sys.objects` or `sp_addextendedproperty`, etc.)